# Create a json array from only a few Mysql fields while outputting the others

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a json array from only the `id` and `name` fields below, while outputting the others. How can I best achieve this? I'm trying to get the output like this:

```
Peter    30     1 Elm Street 91550  {"userId":"1","userName":"Peter"}
James    31     2 Elm Street 91551  {"userId":"2","userName":"James"}
John     32     3 Elm Street 91552  {"userId":"3","userName":"John"}
Andrew   34     4 Elm Street 91553  {"userId":"4","userName":"Andrew"}
```

I'll use the json array for something else later in a different form. The array keys have to remain the same and cannot be changed.

The output script is pretty simple like this.

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select id, name, age, address, pincode from json");
    $stmt->execute();

    while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {

        echo $row['name']." ".$row['age']." ".$row['address']." ".$row['pincode'];

    }
```

I'm currently doing like this, but do you see a better way to do it?

```
while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
        echo $row['name']." ".$row['age']." ".$row['address']." ".$row['pincode'];

        $myarray['userId'] = $row['id'];
        $myarray['userName'] = $row['name'];

        echo json_encode($myarray);
        echo '<br>';
    }
```

There are many more fields that'll go into the array. I've used only a few for this example.

Comment: What you have done is fine.  I don't see a problem.

Comment: I'm trying to make it cleaner, shorter.

Comment: @ScottWilson, The OP is looking for a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of having less lines and a save the use of a variable you can do it like this:

```
while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
        echo $row['name']." ".$row['age']." ".$row['address']." ".$row['pincode'];

        echo json_encode(array('userId' => $row['id'], 'userName' => $row['name']));
        echo '<br>';
    }
```

Another way, wold be to print your values with a *foreach*. About the *Json*, well, the same as before...

```
while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
    foreach ($row as $value)
    {
        echo $value.' ';
    }

    echo json_encode(array('userId' => $row['id'], 'userName' => $row['name']));
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Nice approach, but your second block of code outputs everything twice. I'm using the top one, but just in case other novices check here...

Comment: @jmenezes, You are right. It prints twice because of how fetch works. It gives an array with 2 different keys. (numerical and column name). If you are ussing PDO, you can use this parameter: _PDO::FETCH_ASSOC_

Answer (score 0):

Try with **fetch_array** like

```
$result = $stmt->fetch_array();
json_encode($result);
```

and dont use mysql_* functions due to it is depricated,instead you can use mysqli_* or pdo statements 
**REFER** [**THIS**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

You can also use **fetchAll()**;but i think it will used in PDO only